# Setting state in React useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my app I fetch data from my API after a button is clicked that changes the state of `endpoint`. Until the data is fetched I want to display a loading icon. After MUCH testing, I finally got it to work. This is what it looks like:

```js
  const [endpoint, setEndpoint] = useState('products');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    fetch(`/api/${endpoint}`, {
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      setData(data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      setData([]);
    })
    .finally(() => setLoading(false));

  }, [endpoint]);

  const onSelect = (option) => {
    setEndpoint(option);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar onSelect={onSelect}/>
      <div className="main">
        <Banner />
        {loading ? 'Loading...' : JSON.stringify(data)}
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Even though I get the result that I want, I'm a bit confused as to how it all fits together because I'm new to React. Please correct me If I'm wrong, but this is my understanding:

`setEndpoint` triggers a re-render, which causes `useEffect` to execute because it has a dependency on `endpoint`. Each set state call inside `useEffect` also causes a re-render. For instance when `setLoading(true)` is called, the screen is re-rendered to show 'Loading...'. Once the state of `loading` is set to `true`, `fetch` gets called. As soon as the promise is resolved, `setData(data)` causes another re-render. However, my data isn't displayed on screen **until** `setLoading(false)` is called, re-rendering the screen yet again, displaying my data. So in total, the screen is re-rendered 3 times (right?).

I'm still confused because I was under the impression that hooks like `useEffect` are **asynchronous** so why would it wait for the state to be set before continuing to execute the next lines of code?

Comment: It *may* re-render that many times; state updates can be batched. There's no "once the state of `loading` is set to true"; the code will continue immediately after the call to `setState`. `setState` is asynchronous (not in the sense it's `await`able). Your data isn't displayed until `loading` is false because that's what you told it to do.

Comment: Then, are set state calls queued and eventually executed in that order? Maybe I need to brush up on how the js engine works

Comment: setData(data) and setLoading(false) happen right after one another so they probably get batched together.

Comment: They can be *batched*, e.g., two setStates in a row *may* be a single state update. This is not a JS engine thing, but React.

Answer (score 2):

The `useEffect` hook callback is *completely* synchronous. What you are seeing is the asynchronous Promise chain at work.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true); // (3)

  fetch(`/api/${endpoint}`, { // (4)
    method: 'GET',
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      setData(data); // (6)
    })
    .catch(e => {
      setData([]); // (6)
    })
    .finally(() => setLoading(false)); // (7)
}, [endpoint]); // (2)

const onSelect = (option) => {
  setEndpoint(option); // (1)
}

...

{loading ? 'Loading...' : JSON.stringify(data)} // (5), (8)
```

What you explain as your understanding is largely correct.

1. An `endpoint` state update is ***enqueued*** the callback function completes and the state updates is ***processed***, triggering a rerender.
2. The `useEffect` hook is called, its dependencies checked. Since `endpoint` value updated, the `useEffect` callback is invoked.
3. A `loading` state update is ***enqueued***. The callback function is still running.
4. A `fetch` request is made. `fetch` returns a Promise, and the code starts a Promise chain. This chain is asynchronous. The `useEffect` hook callback now completes and since there is no more synchronous code to run. The `loading` state update is **processed** and a rerender is triggered.
5. The UI conditionally renders the loading indicator.
6. Here the Promise chain has either resolved or rejected, a `data` state update is **enqueued** and a Promise returned in the chain. The `data` state update is **processed** and a rerender triggered.
7. The end of the Promise chain, a `loading` state update is **enqueued**. The `loading` state is **processed** and a rerender is triggered.
8. The UI now conditionally renders the data.

> So in total, the screen is re-rendered 3 times (right?).

By my count the logic above likely triggered 4 rerenders, but React could have potentially rerendered any number of times for just about any other reason. React components rerender when either state or props update, or the parent component rerenders.